# COBOL: How to turn off SCREEN and come back to terminal

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I'm displaying to user a form, defined in SCREEN SECTION. After user input I'd like to clear the screen and go back to **terminal**. But I have no idea how to do it. Every next DISPLAY "something" puts data back at first row of screen. I don't want to use SCREEN anymore, no LINE statements.

```
[...]

SCREEN SECTION.
01 USER-FORM.
[...]
01  CLEAR-SCREEN.
    05 BLANK SCREEN.

[...]

DISPLAY USER-FORM.
ACCEPT USER-FORM.
DISPLAY CLEAR-SCREEN.

PERFORM DATA-CALCULATIONS.

DISPLAY "CALCULATION RESULTS 1: " WS-DATA(1).
DISPLAY "CALCULATION RESULTS 2: " WS-DATA(2).
DISPLAY "CALCULATION RESULTS 3: " WS-DATA(3).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Once you've used a SCREEN in GnuCOBOL, all subsequent DISPLAYs/ACCEPTs are on the screen.

If you don't want to explicitly specify the LINE and COL for the subsequent DISPLAYs, you can use `LINE 0` extension, which gives something like the usual DISPLAY behaviour (namely, `LINE 0` positions the DISPLAY at the start of the line following the last ACCEPT/DISPLAY).

```
DISPLAY "CALCULATION RESULTS 1: " LINE 0, WS-DATA(1).
DISPLAY "CALCULATION RESULTS 2: " LINE 0, WS-DATA(2).
DISPLAY "CALCULATION RESULTS 3: " LINE 0, WS-DATA(3).
```

Comment: "You can't" sounds so harsh.maybe change to "you can't without adjusting GnuCOBOL first"? Seems like a relevant and easy to implement feature request ;-)

Comment: @SimonSobisch - I'm not sure I want the GnuCOBOL to disembark from canonical COBOL train. But maybe it's good suggestion after all, if I can only explain clearly to developers what I'm *really* after.

Comment: @aceJacek Sounds like you want the option to enter/leave the internal terminal used for "extended display" (if I remember correctly GnuCOBOL, ACUCOBOL and MF huse something like this and so far only MicroFocus has some option to get in/out via `CALL "someroutine-possibly-hey-something" USING somethingstrange-found-in-the-docs`.
The point is: it is not necessarily "COBOL behavior" in the first place, more an implementation detail.

Comment: @SimonSobisch done. https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/feature-requests/380/